# unable to run compiled .class java file in Win7 cmd

Tags: java, cmd, compilation, telnet

issue is the following when trying to use Apache's java telnet solution in win7 cmd:

I keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class TelnetClientExample.class" message when trying to run a compiled .class file from cmd.

```
C:\Users\IB>java -cp C:\Users\IB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TelnetClientExample\build\classes TelnetClientExample 192.168.0.13 23
```

In NetBeans it works well (of course with changing params from args to variables from stdin), but in cmd I'm unable to run it.

code is copy-paste from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ExampleofuseofTelnetClient.htm (except package name which is "telnetclientexample" in my project).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a CLASSPATH problem, netbeans could be using a different classpath, check where the class is and add it to the class path. Or you could compile you project into a jar and put the dependencies inside.

If that doesn't help, perhaps the path itself is wrong, check for package names, they need to be complete on your java command

Comment: I tried creating jar file, but resulted the same:
C:\Users\IB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TelnetClientExample\build\classes>java -jar telnet.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class telnetclientexample.TelnetClientExample

C:\Users\IB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TelnetClientExample\build\classes>jar tf telnet.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
commons-net-3.3.jar
telnetclientexample/TelnetClientExample.class

Path is correct, so I have no clue why main class cannot be located. Entry point has been provided when I created the jar file

Answer (score 0):

If the class is in the package `telnetclientexample`, then its name is

```
telnetclientexample.TelnetClientExample
```

and you must thus use

```
java -cp C:\Users\IB\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TelnetClientExample\build\classes telnetclientexample.TelnetClientExample 192.168.0.13 23
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your TelnetClientExample.java file your class identifier(class name) is not same as your file name... Consider following program:

```
class hello{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("HI");
    }
}}
```

Here suppose I save this file as **Hello.java** and on compilation it compile well, but gives the same error as you mentioned in your question:

> G:\ZPREP>javac Hello.java
>
> G:\ZPREP>java Hello
> Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
>
> G:\ZPREP>

This is because I am saving file name with name "Hello" and the class name is "hello" because java is case sensitive it consider 'H' and 'h' is different, so I think in your case after compilation **TelnetClientExample.class** is generated with no error but may be you saved file with different name...